# high resolution images with Amazon PA-API 5.0

Tags: amazon-web-services

the product sheets on the **Amazon site** contain **high resolution images** (*those when you move the mouse over the photo in evidence*)

For example, for this product https://www.amazon.it/dp/B01D9KXE0K, looking in the html code, we can find:

```
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ieQLijPXL._AC_SL1300_.jpg
```

***71ieQLijPXL.*AC_SL1300*.jpg*** *(1155 x 918 pixel)*

Portion of html code:

```
var data = {'colorImages': {'initial': [{"hiRes": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ieQLijPXL._AC_SL1300_.jpg", "thumb" : "....
```

along with all the others.

Well I can get them from here too, but how do **I get them with Amazon PA-API 5.0**?

In the official documentation of the images https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/images.html, there are **only Large, Medium or Small** images where the Large have a resolution of 500 x 500 pixels, while those hires taken **from the pagian web have a resolution much higher**.

the same image obtained with API is this https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41bdFTTeGPL.jpg, which obviously has a different name

***41bdFTTeGPL.jpg*** *(500 x 500 pixel)*

Anyone know **how to get them with Amazon PA-API 5.0**?

Comment: I presume there is no way to get high resolution images via Amazon PA-API. Now, that they stopped the sitestrip tool, there is no economic way of getting high quality images from Amazon anymore. From my point of view, the decision, making it harder for affiliates to promote their articles is perplexing and short-sighted...